# Issue with jQuery transfert effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to implement the jQuery dialog UI, to show a certain message to the user.

I have included the jQuery library in my HTML page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

My JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click',function(){
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      width:"auto",
      height:"auto",
      show: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "transfer",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  } );
})
```

### Problem

The dialog opens but doesn't close, no matter how many times I try to close it, this error pops up:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
> at e.effects.effect.transfer (jquery-ui.min.js:11:4184)
> at HTMLDivElement.i (jquery-ui.min.js:10:24550)
> at Function.dequeue (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3:2066)
> at HTMLDivElement. (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3:2522)
> at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:2973)
> at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:835)
> at m.fn.init.queue (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3:2427)
> at m.fn.init.effect (jquery-ui.min.js:10:24778)
> at m.fn.init.hide (jquery-ui.min.js:10:25098)
> at e.Widget. [as _hide] (jquery-ui.min.js:6:13404)

I even tried closing the dialog programmatically

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

But it still shows the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [jQuery transfer effect documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/transfer-effect/).

That effect needs a "destination". It has to be another element.
So there will be an animation between the element on which the effect is called **TO** another element...

And please upgrade the versions you are using!!! jQuery 1.11.1 is more than 10 years old.

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: "auto",
  height: "auto",
  show: {
    effect: "slide",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "transfer",
    to: $(".transfer-destination"), // A destination was missing
    duration: 1000
  }
})

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open")
})
```

```css
button{
  margin-bottom:2em;
}

.transfer-destination {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 10em;
}

.ui-effects-transfer {  /* this is styling for the transitionning element */
  border: 2px dotted red;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/theme.min.css" />

<button id="save">Save</button><br>
<div class="transfer-destination">Destination of the closed dialog</div>

<div id="dialog" class="">A certain message</div>
```